# Kubernetes POD IP space

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. If I am in a AWS EKS cluster and I deploy say 20 PODs.

Will each of these PODs acquire an IP from the AWS VPC CIDR? Meaning 20 IPs from the VPC CIDR are now blocked for each POD?

OR

Does the POD IPs are internal to the EKS and have no impact on the IP space available on the VPC CIDR? The EKS Service may acquire one IP from the VPC CIDR, but that's about it.

Thanks.

p.s. I was redirected from stackoverflow to ask this question in serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the networking solution implemented. The default

> CNI plugin is responsible for allocating VPC IP addresses to Kubernetes nodes and configuring the necessary networking for pods on each node.

[EKS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html)

> Amazon EKS only officially supports the Amazon VPC CNI plugin. Amazon EKS runs upstream Kubernetes and is certified Kubernetes conformant however, so alternate CNI plugins will work with Amazon EKS clusters.

From the [EKS VPC networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html). If you hit this limitation you can use Calico for example:

> You can also use Calico for networking on EKS in place of the default AWS VPC networking without the need to use IP addresses from the underlying VPC. This allows you to take advantage of the full set of Calico networking features, including Calico’s flexible IP address management capabilities.

[projectcalico getting started guide](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/eks)

In any way I would recommend you to stick with the default configuration as AWS recommends:

> The default value provides enough IP addresses for most implementations, but if it doesn't, then you can change it.

[EKS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html) Looking at the CloudFormation template they are using a `/16` VPC block with `/18` subnets. A `/18` subnet will give you `16,382` usable hosts per subnet. That should be enough for most usecases.

Comment: thanks. My need is to save VPC IP addresses as much as possible because the same AWS VPC I will have my EKS in, will also be hosting multipe other services that require dedicated IPs. By eliminating the IP requirement of the PODs, I can save these IPs for other usage in the VPC.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will hit this limitation. Design your EKS subnets large enough and there should still be enough space for subnets housing ec2 instances outside of EKS. If you really run out of IP addresses you can create a dedicated VPC for EKS or ec2 and use VPC peering between those if necessary.